# Reconnect wireguard to another VPN server if ping fails?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cron

I am using WireGuard for connecting to Mullvads (= vpn service) vpn servers. In total I am using 5 different wireguard vpn configs (vpn servers*). Called server1, server2, server3, server4, server5.

So to connect to server3 I run `wg-quick up server3`, and to disconnect from *current server* - server3 - `wg-quick down server3`

Sometimes the vpn server goes down. I want an almost instant reconnect to another one of the 5 available servers. What can I do to make this work automatically?

crontab:

```
*/3 * * * * ping -c4 google.com || wg-command-here?
```

So every 3rd minute google.com will be pinged. If fail, then it will run `wg-command-here`. Which will be what =D?

So whenever ping fails => disconnect from *current* wireguard server => connect to another one of the total 5 available (random, but *preferably* not the one its currently connected to for obvious reasons).

Does anyone have a neat script that can solve this? I have Googled for **2 days** without finding a damn solution at all. It gotta be possible what the hell :o. I have ZERO programming knowledge so I am really hoping for a copypaste solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a script Which check the connection time to time
script ping the server when server is online it connect to the wiregaurd vpn and check the connected server time to time if connected server ping fails 3 times it check the another server by ping

change serverip in script before running

script

```
#!/bin/bash
server1IP= 84.18.418.64 #change server1 ip or name 
server2IP= 84.18.418.687 #change server2 ip or name 
server3IP= 845.158.418.64 #change server3 ip or name 
server4IP= 44.168.418.64 #change server4 ip or name 
server5IP= 64.68.418.64 #change server5 ip or name 
while true
do
if /bin/ping -c 1 $server1Ip
    then
            sudo wg-quick up server1
            tries=0
            while [[ $tries -lt 3 ]]
            do
            if /bin/ping -c 1 $server1Ip
                then
                        tries=0
                        continue
            fi
            tries=$((tries+1))
            done
            sudo wg-quick down server1
fi

if /bin/ping -c 1 $server2Ip
    then
            sudo wg-quick up server2
            tries=0
            while [[ $tries -lt 3 ]]
            do
            if /bin/ping -c 1 $server2Ip
                then
                        tries=0
                        continue
            fi
            tries=$((tries+1))
            done
            sudo wg-quick down server2
fi

if /bin/ping -c 1 $server3Ip
    then
            sudo wg-quick up server3
            tries=0
            while [[ $tries -lt 3 ]]
            do
            if /bin/ping -c 1 $server3Ip
                then
                        tries=0
                        continue
            fi
            tries=$((tries+1))
            done
            sudo wg-quick down server3
fi

if /bin/ping -c 1 $server4Ip
    then
            sudo wg-quick up server4
            tries=0
            while [[ $tries -lt 3 ]]
            do
            if /bin/ping -c 1 $server4Ip
                then
                        tries=0
                        continue
            fi
            tries=$((tries+1))
            done
            sudo wg-quick down server4
fi

if /bin/ping -c 1 $server5Ip
    then
            sudo wg-quick up server5
            tries=0
            while [[ $tries -lt 3 ]]
            do
            if /bin/ping -c 1 $server5Ip
                then
                        tries=0
                        continue
            fi
            tries=$((tries+1))
            done
            sudo wg-quick down server5
fi
done
```

save this script as wiregaurd.sh
or download it
https://anonfiles.com/p3Y94av1u6/wiregaurd_sh

sudo chmod +x wiregaurd.sh

sudo sed -i -e 's/\r$//' wiregaurd.sh

sudo nohup "./wiregaurd.sh" &

OR

run this script at start up as
put this in crontab

@reboot [path to wiregaurd script]